# Single access point for several azure vm's

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

Is there a way to set up a single entry point that will direct me to one of the open machines?

I have a number of VM's that are used by a number of different people.  Rather than having them log into a specific VM, I would like them to be able to log in to an entry point that will auto connect them to an available machine. When I say log in we use RDP.*

I'm trying to make it easier to log in rather than designating the specific machine each time.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [Remote desktop connection broker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772245.aspx) is for, to seamlessly allocate session hosts to user.

Comment: You're alive :)

Comment: @Iain Just about :) Just been very very busy!

Answer (score 0):

in Azure, all IaaS VM's are inside a DNS container (cloud service)

Azure automatically directs traffic to the correct location.

Have a look at this MVA course and get back to me if you need any further advice.

https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/microsoft-azure-iaas-deep-dive-jump-start-8287

Enjoy 
and don't forget to mark as the answer if it helps and vote as helpful in any case

Yours

Ed